# Estado inicial JComboBox

Tags: java, eventos, interfaz-gráfica

Estoy haciendo un programa donde cierta ventana tiene una lista desplegable (`JComboBox`) donde se debe mostrar algo en base a la opción seleccionada en dicha lista. Comencé a hacerlo de la manera más sencilla para luego complejizarlo a medida que sea necesario, por lo que creé un `JFrame` vacío con un `JPanel` en el cual añadí un `JComboBox` inicializado con un arreglo de 5 opciones (para comenzar, simplemente llamé a estas opciones `option A`, `option B` y así hasta `option E`).

Luego busqué cómo agregar algun handler de eventos como el `ActionListener` pero para `JComboBox`, y encontré la interfaz `ItemListener` que sirve para esto, por lo que creé una clase llamada `ItemChangeListener` que reaccione a los cambios en la selección de los items del `JComboBox`. Para esto, hice un override del método `itemStateChanged`. Por el momento simplemente hice que la clase imprima la letra correspondiente a la opción seleccionada. Esta clase quedó de la forma:

```
private class ItemChangeListener implements ItemListener {

        @Override
        public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent event) {
           if (event.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) {
              Object item = event.getItem();

              switch (item.toString()) {
                  case "option A": {
                      System.out.println("A");  
                      break;
                  }

                  case "option B": {
                      System.out.println("B");  
                      break;
                  }

                  case "option C": {
                      System.out.println("C");  
                      break;
                  }

                  case "option D": {
                      System.out.println("D");  
                      break;
                  }

                  default: {
                      System.out.println("E");
                      break;
                  }
              }
           }
        }
}
```

Esto funciona perfecto por el momento. Es sólo código para entender el funcionamiento y poder manejarlo bien antes de trabajar más a fondo.

La ventana se despliega con el `JComboBox` inicializado en `option A`, y cada vez que cambio la opción seleccionada se muestra en consola la letra correspondiente al item (lógicamente, si estoy en `option C` y selecciono nuevamente `option C`, no ocurre nada porque el item no cambió), como se puede ver a continuación:

[image: Funcionamiento correcto al cambiar item]

Ahora, la duda es cómo hacer que cuando el `JComboBox` sea creado e inicializado en `option A` se muestre en consola la salida correspondiente a este estado inicial en el que fue creado (en este caso, la salida sería "A"). Entiendo que `ItemChangeListener` sólo reacciona ante un cambio de estado dado por el usuario, por lo que al inicializar el frame, el `JComboBox` no ha tenido ningún cambio de estado y esto hace que no se muestre en consola la salida "A".

Estuve leyendo algunos métodos en la API sobre `JComboBox` e `ItemListener` pero no estoy seguro de cómo utilizarlos correctamente.

¿Alguna idea?

Desde ya, muchas gracias a todos.

Comment: Después de agregar las opciones, haz el llamado explícito al método `setSelectedItem()`.

Comment: Lo hice, pero al no ser un evento desatado por el usuario, la clase que implementa ```ItemListener``` no reacciona a tal acción. Luego de leer un poco más me topé con [este documento de ejemplo de Oracle sobre JComboBox](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/components/ComboBoxDemoProject/src/components/ComboBoxDemo.java) y traté de seguir sus pasos con ```actionPerformed```, y funcionó.

Comment: ¿Agregas el listener antes o después agregar las opciones?

Comment: Primero agrego las opciones (```JComboBox<String> comboBox = new JComboBox<>(options);```), luego agrego el listener y luego de eso intento hacer uso de ```setSelectedItem()``` pero no reacciona